# Posting multipart request containing jpg and json causes interal server error and win32 status 64 on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, iis, asp.net-web-api

My winforms app sends PUT/POST requests to asp.net web api service. Mostly it sends json object as request's content and those request work well. Sometimes, when it needs to send jpg along with json object, so it creates multiPart request where jpg is content and json is passed in url, like so:

```
example.com/EditPart?id=193&PartJson=<serialized json object>
```

Here's full definition of the method sending the request:

```
public async void Edit(string attachmentPath)
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff" });
                string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Edit{typeof(T).Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + $"&id={this.Id}&UserId={RuntimeSettings.UserId}" + $"&{typeof(T).Name}Json={serializedProduct}";
                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                try
                {
                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(attachmentPath))
                    {
                        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(attachmentPath);
                        StreamContent fcontent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                        fcontent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                        fcontent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fileInfo.Name + "\"");
                        content.Add(fcontent, "file", fileInfo.Name);
                        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                        var result = await client.PutAsync(url, content);//<--stops here
                        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Edycja zakończona powodzeniem!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Serwer zwrócił błąd przy próbie edycji. Wiadomość: " + result.ReasonPhrase);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Problem z wysyłką żądania do serwera. Wiadomość: " + ex.Message + ". " + ex.InnerException.Message, "Błąd żądania", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
```

It goes to `await client.PutAsync(url, content);` and then straight to exception saying: **An error occurred while sending the request. The underlaying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on receive.**

When I check in IIS logs, I see the request gets properly to the server, but ends with status 500 and win32 status 64.. I even put logging with NLog to EditPart method, but it never fires.. It looks like the method isn't called at all, but of course from IIS logs I know it is.

Here's complete EditPart definition on asp.net web api:

```
[HttpPut]
        [Route("EditPart")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]

        public HttpResponseMessage EditPart(string token, int id, int UserId, string PartJson)
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                JDE_Parts item = jss.Deserialize<JDE_Parts>(PartJson);

                try
                {
                    var items = db.JDE_Parts.Where(u => u.PartId == id);
                    if (items.Any())
                    {
                        Logger.Info("EditPart: Znalazłem odpowiednią część. Przystępuję do edycji Id={id}, UserId={UserId}", id, UserId);
                        JDE_Parts orgItem = items.FirstOrDefault();

                        //handle image

                        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                        if (httpRequest.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            //there's a new content
                            if (httpRequest.ContentLength > Static.RuntimeSettings.MaxFileContentLength)
                            {
                                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, $"{item.Name} przekracza dopuszczalną wielość pliku ({Static.RuntimeSettings.MaxFileContentLength} MB) i został odrzucony");
                            }

                            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
                            string filePath = "";
                            if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                Logger.Info("EditPart: Znaleziono nowe pliki. Przystępuję do zapisu na dysku. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}", id, UserId);
                                var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));

                                filePath = $"{Static.RuntimeSettings.Path2Files}{item.Token + ext.ToLower()}";

                                string oFileName = db.JDE_Parts.Where(p => p.PartId == id).FirstOrDefault().Image;
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oFileName))
                                {
                                    // There was a file, must delete it first
                                    Logger.Info("EditPart: Istnieją poprzednie pliki pod tą nazwą. Przystępuję do usuwania. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}", id, UserId);
                                    System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(RuntimeSettings.Path2Files, oFileName));
                                    System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(RuntimeSettings.Path2Thumbs, oFileName));
                                }
                                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                                Logger.Info("EditPart: Zapisano pliki. Przystępuję do utworzenia miniatury.. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}", id, UserId);
                                Static.Utilities.ProduceThumbnail(filePath);
                                item.Image = item.Token + ext.ToLower();
                            }

                        }

                        try
                        {
                            Logger.Info("EditPart: Przystępuję do zapisu zmian w bazie danych. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}", id, UserId);
                            db.Entry(orgItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
                            db.Entry(orgItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            Logger.Info("EditPart: Zapisano zmiany w bazie. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}", id, UserId);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Logger.Error("Błąd w EditPart. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}. Szczegóły: {Message}, nowa wartość: {item}", id, UserId, ex.ToString(), item);
                            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Logger.Error("Błąd w EditPart. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}. Szczegóły: {Message}, nowa wartość: {item}", id, UserId, ex.ToString(), item);
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("Błąd w EditPart. Id={id}, UserId={UserId}. Szczegóły: {Message}", id, UserId, ex.ToString());
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

What's weird is that all this worked perfectly  well for months, until some time ago it stopped.. Also, when I debug the asp.net application on my machine, the request runs without any problem.. What else I can do to trace this issue?

Comment: HTTP 500 error is a general error indicating something went wrong on server.  windows error 64 indicates the Network Name is no longer available.  I suspect the error is due to the TLS authentication that occurs using TCP at beginning of the request.  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security leaks.  In June this year Microsoft pushed a security update that disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 servers and force clients to use TLS 1.2 or later.  Your request is probably still using the default TLS version.

Comment: Try :  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12.    See : https://inthetechpit.com/2018/12/15/tls-version-handling-with-http-web-request-csharp/

Comment: Thanks jdweng, but it's not it. I've placed System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; before making request but it didn't change a thing.. It makes sense because there's another version of this method sending request to the same API but WITHOUT file, and it's been working correctly

Comment: May be the certificate doesn't support the encryption mode/key for TLS 1.2.  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see if the TSL completed.

Comment: I used Fiddler but it only says 504 ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes. I guess I will change the server method for multipart containing file and json in form fields and test how it goes

Comment: Error 504 is a timeout error.  The error could mean a few things 1) The URL is not valid 2) The authentication did not pass so server is ignoring the request. 3) The request is not formatted properly.  If the request need a valid id the server could ignore request. 4)  The server attempted to connect to a database and did not get a response.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug the asp.net api application, it can run without any problem. This shows that there is no problem with the api application.

But the status in IIS logs is 500, errors greater than 500 are generally caused by the server, the client is normal. This contradicts the above conclusion that the api is no problem.

Since I don’t know the version of .net you are using, I’m not sure whether to use TLS 1.0, 1.1 or 1.2.  Different versions of .net target different TLS, the latest 4.6 currently supports 1.2.  So the most safe and effective way is to set all TLS and SSL.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12| SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Comment: It's Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10 and .Net framework 4.7.03062. I don't think it's related to TLS/SSL, all other methods on the same Asp.net web api service work just fine, the problem only concerns requests with file attached. I tried putting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12| SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;` before making request, but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Have you check the fail request tracing?May be it will show more about process in application.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was single line in my Edit method in the client app. After changing `fcontent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")` to `fcontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileInfo.Name))` it works flawlessly. In other words, my request wasn't even sent to the server. What's puzzling, though, is the fact that the same code had been working for months and then stopped..

```
public async void Edit(string attachmentPath)
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var serializedProduct = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff" });
            string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + $"Edit{typeof(T).Name}?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + $"&id={this.Id}&UserId={RuntimeSettings.UserId}" + $"&{typeof(T).Name}Json={serializedProduct}";
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(attachmentPath))
                {
                    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(attachmentPath);
                    StreamContent fcontent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                    fcontent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileInfo.Name)); //fcontent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                    fcontent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fileInfo.Name + "\"");
                    content.Add(fcontent, "file", fileInfo.Name);
                    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    var result = await client.PutAsync(url, content);//<--stops here
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Edycja zakończona powodzeniem!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Serwer zwrócił błąd przy próbie edycji. Wiadomość: " + result.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Problem z wysyłką żądania do serwera. Wiadomość: " + ex.Message + ". " + ex.InnerException.Message, "Błąd żądania", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```